# Monitoring the shell through python

Tags: python

Quick and simple: I'm calling a process with subprocess.popen which will run continuously in cmd/terminal.  I want to call a function if a certain string of text is displayed in cmd/terminal.  How would I do this?  I'm rather new to python, so the simplest solution will probably be the best one.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output you are looking for is either coming from `stdout` or `stderr`. Let's assume it's coming from `stdout`. (If it is coming from `stderr` the solution is analogous; just change `stdout` to `stderr`, below.)

```
import subprocess
PIPE = subprocess.PIPE

proc = subprocess.Popen(['ls'], stdout=PIPE)
for line in iter(proc.stdout.readline, ''):
    if line.startswith('a'):
        print(line)
```

Replace `line.startswith('a')` with whatever condition is appropriate, and (of course) replace `['ls']` with whatever command you desire.

Comment: Actually, one more little question, how would I do it if the string I'm looking for isn't at the beginning of the line?  Is the a line.contains() method, or something of the sort?

Comment: Use `if "string I'm looking for" in line`.

Answer (score 1):

The only problem with @unutbu code is (but that doesn't apply to your case, it's more in general) is that it blocks your application on every `readline` call. So you cannot do anything else.

If you want a nonblocking solution you should create a file, open it in the write and read mode, pass the writer to `Popen` and read from the reader. Reading from the reader will always be non-blocking.

```
import io
import time
import subprocess

filename = 'temp.file'
with io.open(filename, 'wb') as writer, io.open(filename, 'rb', 1) as reader:
    process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=writer)
    # Do whatever you want in your code
    data = reader.read() # non-blocking read
    # Do more stuff
    data = reader.read() # another non-blocking read...
    # ...
```

And so on...

This doesn't apply for your particular case in which the @unutbu's solution works perfectly well. I added it just for completeness sake...